# How to check the available space on the hard disk each day and if it is lower than 1GO remove files

Tags: linux, scripting, cron, disk-usage, rm

I need to make a planned task : 
Check the available space on the hard disk each day and remove files if this condition is verified : Available < 1Go.

Here is the script that I wrote but doesn't seem to work :

```
var="df -h | sed -n 2p |awk '{ print $4 }' "
if[var<15];then
./bin/dss stop
rm -rf tmp/*
rm -rf caches/*
./bin/dss start
fi
```

I didn't do the crontab part yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(df -h | sed -n 2p |awk '{ print $4 }')
if [ "${var}" le "15" ]
then
./bin/dss stop
rm -rf tmp/*
rm -rf caches/*
./bin/dss start
fi
```

Comment: DON'T try that code, unless you are sure there is no subdirectory named ` / ` (i.e. "space", and another file or directory "space" under it), or a variation of it.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík, hmh, what? If you have files `␣` and `a` inside `tmp/`, `rm` will get the arguments `-rf`, `tmp/␣`, `tmp/a`. What's the problem? You're not confusing this with having a variable with `tmp/␣/` and expanding that without quotes, are you?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advice against parsing `df` output.

If you have `stat` from GNU coreutils, you can get the number of free blocks available for non-root by

```
stat  -f /mountpoint -c '%a'
```

the block size by

```
stat -f /mountpoint -c '%S'
```

and the condition can be succintly written as:

```
[ `stat  -f /mountpoint -c '%a'` -lt 262144 ] && do_your_stuff
```

(assuming the block size is 4096 and 1 GB is 1073741824 bytes - i.e. 1073741824/4096)

And as for the deleting (files, as per the question), probably the safest way would be:

```
find /directory -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm -f
```

or even better:

```
find /directory -type f -delete
```

Using `rm -f /something/*` is just asking for troubles.

Comment: Here too: _"Using rm -f /something/* is just asking for troubles."_ -- care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inputs.

This solution worked for me.

var=$(df -h | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $4}')

vari = $(echo "${var::-1}")

if [ $vari < 15 ];

then

./bin/dss stop

rm -rf tmp/*

rm -rf caches/*

./bin/dss start;

fi